# Refer to other projects in the project in node js

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner who has just started node js.

Now my project is made up of one, but I have to separate the API server and the WEB server while doing the project. So, `API <-> Core <-> WEB` We want to make a structure that API and WEB server use Core in common.

But in the API server, I refer to Core as `../../../` but it does not work. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Really can't tell if this is a question about how to organize your source code in the file system to share code between two servers or something else?  You should be able to just put shared modules in a shared location and then load them from there with `require()` as needed from any project.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want. 
If you are connecting the port and using Core's service, you would need to request localhost/yourCoreRoute

If you are referring to file system, ../../ may works

Comment: Hello James Maa. I want to access an external library like git submodule.

Comment: You may do var something = require('../../someLibrary.js')